# Retaining ASP.NET Control values througn their ID does NOT work for FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using the following technique to retain the value of **ASP.NET** controls. It kind of works for every control except the **FileUpload** control.

Does anyone know why and how to find a way around this issue?

I don't want to end up storing FileUpload as Session variables since I have no idea how many of these controls the user will want to generate and keeping track of all the generated **FileUpload** controls that will be created in Session is not something that I would feel right with or look forward to.

The following routine is fantastic but I just can't see the reason why the **FileUpload** in being the exception.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

[image]

Comment: Without looking through the link, I can say that File Upload controls are designed specifically to not allow a coder to specify what file to upload. If you think about it you'll realize why this is necessarily so. Otherwise a coder might prefill the file upload control with for instance `c:\secret\passwords.txt` and get the users passwords...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this procedure should be done somehow since this could be the requirement for some applications.  For instance you get that with a mail clients or applications that require people to upload contents.  I guess my question should be rephrased as what is the best way to implement such requirement like file attachments in an email client where there could be a number of files that would need to be uploaded through automatic field generation.  How would you go about that?  What is you recommendation if this control is insecure and can only be used once.

Comment: Ok, so the *real* question is more along the lines of "How can I allow a user of my web page to upload an unknown number of files?". Correct?

Comment: That's right.  Please look at the question to get a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the uploaded file collection using this code :

```
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("MyFiles") + "\\" +
          System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
        Response.Write("<b>File: </b>" + hpf.FileName + " <b>Size:</b> " +
            hpf.ContentLength + " <b>Type:</b> " + hpf.ContentType + " Uploaded Successfully <br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer.  If you could have a look at the posted image in the question area, you would notice that when the user clicks on "Add More" a whole new row of controls will be generated inside "Placeholder" control.  Imagine the user load their image file for the first slide and when they press "Add More", the FileUpload control gets reset to blank.  My problem is that I'd like to have the user to enter all the values and files and hit the upload once they're done.

Comment: I cannot see the postage image. However Can you add Jquery which will create new row when creating on "Add More" button?

Comment: The new row is generated using the method described in the link provided.  They all get generated through post back.  So in this specific scenario there is no jQuery involved.  The actual code behind is too long to put in this question but by looking the link you would get the idea.  Regards

Comment: You have to store the file in session or viewstate  while creating the new row OR you can create the Row using Jquery. So file upload control will not loss the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple sample to get you started. Code in `.aspx` file (uses jquery borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201657/1429080)):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UploadMany.aspx.cs" Inherits="UploadMany" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var currentIndex = 1;
        function appendOneUpload() {
            $('form input:file').last().after($('<br /><input type="file" name="fileUpload' + currentIndex + '"  onchange="appendOneUpload();"/>'));
            currentIndex++;
        }
    </script>
    <input type="file" runat="server" id="fileUpload0" onchange="appendOneUpload();"/> <br />
    <asp:Button ID="uploadButton" runat="server" OnClick="uploadButton_Clicked" />
</asp:Content>
```

Respective code from `.aspx.cs` file:

```
public partial class UploadMany : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void uploadButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var allFiles = Request.Files;
        for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < allFiles.Count; fileIndex++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile oneFile = allFiles[fileIndex];
            if (oneFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //do something with each uploaded file here
                int i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```